# How do you use the : dependent option with a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a many-to-many relationship like this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :calendar_events
  has_many :calendars, :through => :calendar_events
  # ...
end
```

I want to make it so that when I call `some_event.destroy` Ruby on Rails deletes the association records from the `calendar_events` table. Based on the API documentation, I'm assuming you do this...

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :calendar_events, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :calendars, :through => :calendar_events
  # ...
end
```

Is that the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That will delete all the calendar events only.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do :destroy instead of :delete_all. Delete all is faster for large sets of associated objects though.

See the Rails docs on has_many
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001789